# why equilibrium points are important in ODE theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why equilibrium points are important for the study of differential equations $\dot{x(t)} = h(x(t)$? There can be arbitrary sets which are stable, why stable "equilibrium point"s are important ?

Comment: @Amzoti: understood.thanks.

Comment: @Amzoti: But, one dobut. If someone says that $x^*$ is an equilibrium point for the ODE(which may be difficult to solve) then $x(t) = x^*$ is a solution trajectory of it. But, when we are talking about stability of it then that information ($x(t) = x^*$ is a solution trajectory) is of no use. So, my second question why stable "equilibrium" is important is still unanswered.

Comment: @Amzoti: Can you please give me any reference for this.